# Laravel Query: unique() / distinct() query working on server but not on localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

This query works fine on the live server but not on localhost. So on the live server giving data is also correct. But why is it giving an error on localhost?

```
Vote::distinct()->select('product_id')
    ->where('created_at', '>', now()->startOfDay())
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(9)->get();
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3065 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause
> is not in SELECT list, references column
> 'voting_database.votes_table.id' which is not in SELECT list; this is
> incompatible with DISTINCT (Connection: mysql, SQL: select distinct
> `product_id` from `votes` where `created_at` > 2023-04-16 00:00:00
> order by `id` desc limit 9)

I also tried this query, this is working but does not give the last 9 `unique()` if One user votes for many products; this query works otherwise, sometimes showing seven or sometimes six results if Three or Four users vote for One product, so it gives 7 or 6 results. The query is the following.

```
Vote::where('created_at', '>', now()->startOfDay())
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(9)->get()
    ->unique('product_id');
```

I am trying to get a unique `product_id` from the `votes table getting by created_at last 24 hours whoever like. Sometimes 4 or 5 users vote for one product daily, and I need to count 1/unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use groupBy('product_id') instead of distinct(). Modify your query to something like the following.

```
$votes = Vote::select('product_id')
    ->where('created_at', '>', now()->startOfDay())
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->take(9)
    ->get();
```